# При снятии флажка checkbox поменять значения всех радиокнопок на enabled := false

Tags: delphi

Как написать так, чтобы при снятии флажка checkbox все радиокнопки приняли значение enabled := false?

Comment: Напишите что Вы уже сделали сами и где не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Если все радио-кнопки на форме надо погасить, то:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
 if not TCheckBox(Sender).Checked then
   for i:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
     if Components[i] is TRadioButton then
       TRadioButton(Components[i]).Enabled:=False;
end;
```

Если, лежащие на какой-то панели (TWinControl'е), то:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
 if not TCheckBox(Sender).Checked then
   for i:=0 to Panel1.ControlCount-1 do
     if Panel1.Controls[i] is TRadioButton then
       Panel1.Controls[i].Enabled:=False;
end;
```